# PhoneGap+react.js vs. NativeScript in Android hybrid development

Tags: android, cordova, reactjs, nativescript

In our company, we tried to build hybrid APP development framework and used  Cordova/Phonegap as base support. But this lead to serious performance problem. So we decided to make use of react.js to optimize front end performance. However, it works fine for iOS, but there's not too much improvement for Android. Why? Is react.js specific for iOS? And besides, if i turn to NativeScript, is it a better way to solve the performance problem?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually mean React.js or do you mean React Native? I'm going to assume React Native here.

React Native only exist of iOS as of time being. March 30, Vjeux of the React Native Team [said](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/30/community-roundup-26.html#when-is-react-native-android-coming).

```
When is React Native Android coming?
Give us 6 months.
```

NativeScript and React Native is quite similar in many ways and differs in a few. Compared to a web technology based solution you'll definitely see increased performance no matter what non-web-based technology you go for.

Comment: OP said React.js combined with cordova/phonegap. I think cordova/phonegap doesn't work well with React's Virtual DOM.

Comment: Hi, what i mean is not Rreact Native, but pure web-based cordova combined with react.js, which optimize front-end.

Comment: hi, user3741665, what makes you think that cordova doesn't work well with React.js ?